# AttributeError: type object 'h5py.h5r.Reference' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conda, h5py

I am using python 3.6,Tensorflow 1.3, Keras 2.1.2 
I was importing Resnet50 and I got this error"ImportError: `load_model` requires h5py" so I used 
conda install h5py
but then I got this error knowing that the installed version of h5py is 2.9.0[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4Pzw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any solutions for this error?

I am getting the same thing when trying to import tensorflow (v2.0.0) and Python 3.7.3

Traceback:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import keras
  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import applications
  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\applications\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras import layers
  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.layers.advanced_activations import LeakyReLU
  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\advanced_activations.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import tf_utils
  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.utils.multi_gpu_utils import multi_gpu_model
  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\multi_gpu_utils.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.training import Model
  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 42, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine.network import Network
  File "C:\Users\potvin\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\network.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.keras.engine import saving
  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\saving.py", line 38, in <module>
    import h5py
  File "C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\h5py\__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
  File "h5py\h5r.pxd", line 21, in init h5py._conv
  File "h5py\h5r.pyx", line 145, in init h5py.h5r
AttributeError: type object 'h5py.h5r.Reference' has no attribute '__reduce_cython__'
```

Edit: I was able to fix this issue by restarting the kernel.